# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern on IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors, ienumerable

I've got an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter of a method, where `T` is a struct type:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ...

public static class Foo
{
    internal struct CellDiff
    {
        public int RefX;
        public int RefY;
        public object OldValue;
        public object NewValue;
    }

    private static void ItemChanged(IEnumerable<CellDiff> diffs, int cellX, int cellY)
    {
        var change = from CellDiff diff in diffs
                     where diff.RefX == cellX && diff.RefY == cellY
                     select diff;

        ...
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

> (parameter) `IEnumerable<CellDiff> diffs`
>
> Error:
>   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type '`CellDiff`'. '`Where`' not found.

I've also tried doing `diffs.AsQueryable()`, to no avail.

I usually have no problem doing LINQ queries on `IEnumerable<T>`. I'm a bit lost as to what's happening here.

Comment: Are you positive the error is in that part of the code? Aside from a redundant type on the query variable it seems fine

Comment: I just tried your code and its working fine. It seems error is somewhere else.

Comment: @RuneFS 100% sure. If I add the type the error appears, if I remove it the error goes away.

Comment: Have you implemented your own extension methods on either select or Cast?

Comment: what version of .NET / compiler is this? what other libraries are loaded? I wonder if another library is adding things into either System.Linq, or into another namespace in your "..."

Comment: @RuneFS That was the issue. Forgot I'd got a `Cast<T>` extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying the type in LINQ query syntax creates a call to the `Cast` extension method with that type argument.

Do you have your own `Cast` defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

you need to change query like , updated one is like this

```
 var change = from diff in diffs //changed like removed "CellDiff" from this
                     where diff.RefX == cellX && diff.RefY == cellY
                     select diff;
```

thre is no need of `CellDiff`  after from in you query

Comment: Why is this the case? I'm sure I've included the type before and never had a problem.

Comment: @Polynomial - well I never written query by including type like in your query ...but i think there is no need to include type

Comment: @Polynomial it shouldn't be the type is redundant and as such makes no semantic difference

Comment: @both Adding the type adds a call to `.Cast<TWhatever>()`, so in this case it's not really necessary.

Comment: This shouldn't matter; the translation should be identical. Including it is not required, but shouldn't break it.

Comment: @Polynomial Your code builds fine for me. Are you doing something... weird... elsewhere?

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah, I've worked out why thanks to Rawling - I've got a `Cast<T>` extension method somewhere in my code!

Comment: a cast method that does not follow the intended pattern because (different return type)